# Is it possible to execute a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, eval, evaluation, exec, execute

I have to convert a MSSQL stored proc that passes a `varchar` that is a query:

```
INSERT INTO Results
  EXEC (@Expresion);
```

This isn't working. I'm pretty sure that `EXEC` and `EXECUTE` aren't MySQL commands, but `CALL` doesn't work either.

Does anyone know if it's even possible to have something like JavaScript's `eval` function for MySQL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

EXECUTE is a valid command in MySQL. [MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html)

Answer (score 28):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SET @queryString = (
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO user_group (`group_id`,`user_id`) VALUES ', www.vals) as res FROM (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(qwe.asd SEPARATOR ',') as vals FROM ( 
           SELECT CONCAT('(59,', user_id, ')') as asd FROM access WHERE residency = 9 
    ) as qwe 
) as www
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @queryString;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
SET @asd = NULL;
```

Comment: Is there any purpose to the `SET @asd = NULL;` line? I don't understand what this is doing.

Answer (score 23):

**This is the SQL equivalent of `eval(my_string);`:**

```
@Expression = 'SELECT "Hello, World!";';
PREPARE myquery FROM @Expression;
EXECUTE myquery;
```

Basically I combined the existing answers, neither tells you how to do eval exactly.

---

If you want to add parameters, you can use this:

```
@username = "test";
@password = "asdf";
@Expression = 'SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name = ? AND pass = ?;'
PREPARE myquery FROM @Expression;
EXECUTE myquery USING @username, @password;
```

And to answer the original question exactly:

```
@Expression = 'SELECT "Hello, World!";'
PREPARE myquery FROM @Expression;
INSERT INTO Results
  EXECUTE myquery;
```

Note that the `PREPARE ... FROM` statement wants a session variable (prefixed with `@`). If you try to pass a normal variable, it will throw its hands up in the air and it just won't care.

Comment: `@Expression = 'SELECT "Hello, World!";';` doesn't work for me. I'm using MySQL v5.6.30.

Comment: @kenorb Strange because I'm certain this worked on a recent mysql version. Might it have something to do with setting a different delimiter? (I might have done that but forgotten that it affected this.)

Comment: Maybe `SET` is needed before.

Comment: +1 for the rhyme! _it will throw its hands up in the air and it just won't care_
Code works perfectly!

Comment: At MySQL 8.0 I am unable to create a procedure containing INSERT INTO ..... EXECUTE ..... . Not a big issue for me - I have moved INSERT INTO stuff into my expression. I am just curious why it happens while the code worked fine for others.

Answer (score 2):

The [`EXECUTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execute.html) MySQL command can only be used for one prepared statement.

If case you want to execute multiple queries from the string, consider saving them into file and source it, e.g.

```
SET @query = 'SELECT 1; SELECT 2; SELECT 3;';
SELECT @query INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/temp.sql';
SOURCE /tmp/temp.sql;
```