# Exact count of all rows in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I'm currently using the script

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Tables';
```

However, it's not accurate, because the engine used by my MySQL tables is InnoDB (I only realised this could be an issue now, be these databases have existed for a while).

Is there any way to get an exact count of every row in every table of a database with MySQL?

Cheers.

Comment: Because I accidently dropped an 's' in my example. I actually need to count the rows from all the tables in a particular database.

Comment: Extended answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707814/mysql-summarize-all-table-row-counts-in-a-single-query

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692340/mysql-count-all-rows-per-table-for-in-one-query. This question specifically asks about databases with InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the only accurate (and slower) way is to do for every single table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table
```

Comment: @vearutop Dragon Jake mentions in his/her answer that this would need to be run on every single table...

Comment: I wouldn't put everything in SQL query, it seems that MySQL isn't capable of selecting from variable table name. So i came up at least with query generator: `SELECT CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'Tables';`

Comment: Cheers @DragonJake, turns out that's what I had to do. :)

Answer (score 5):

This SQL statement will generate a union query that can complete the task in one step:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT \'', table_name ,'\' as tbl, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', table_name, ') AS ct UNION')
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'your_database';
```

After running the SQL statement, just paste the output into a text editor, delete the word "UNION" from the end of the output, and you will have the union query.

Beware that running the union query could take a lot of resources depending on your database size, load, and hardware, so you may not want to run it all at once.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem which led me to this question.

Thanks to computerGuy12345's answer, I came up with a stored procedure that
does this without having to copy-paste. 
As he said, beware that this will scan each table and might take a while.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `all_tables_rowcount`(databaseName VARCHAR(250))
BEGIN
DECLARE p_done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE p_queryString varchar(250) ;
DECLARE p_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT queryString FROM tmp.tableCountQueries;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET p_done = TRUE;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp.tableCountQueries;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp.tableCounts;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp.tableCounts(TableName varchar(250), RowCount BIGINT) ;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp.tableCountQueries(queryString varchar(250)) AS 
(
    SELECT CONCAT(
        'INSERT INTO tmp.tableCounts(TableName, RowCount) SELECT "', 
        table_name, 
        '", COUNT(*) AS RowCount FROM ', 
        table_schema,
        '.',
        table_name
    ) AS queryString
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE table_schema = databaseName
) ;

OPEN p_cur;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH p_cur INTO p_queryString;
    IF p_done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET @queryString = p_queryString ;
    PREPARE rowcountTable FROM @queryString; 
    EXECUTE rowcountTable ;
END LOOP;

SELECT * FROM tmp.tableCounts ;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

`Select Sum(column_Name) from table` ,can not give the exact count of rows in a table , it wil give total row count+1 , wil give  the next data inserting row also. and one more thing is, in `sum(Column_Name)`  the column_Name should be int ,if it is varchar or char sum function wont work. soo the best thing is use 
       `Select Count(*) from table`    to get exact number of rows in a table.

ThnQ,

Venkat

Answer (score 1):

```
select table_name,table_rows from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='database name';
```

**table_name** means number of tables which is present in "data base "

**table_rows** means number rows in each column

**table_schema** is the database name. from which data base you are looking for the counts

Comment: the table_rows count in INFORMATION_SCHEMA is not accurate for Innodb tables, it's only an approximation.

Comment: Agreed. This will work for non-InnoDB tables but does not address the specific question.

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me

```
    <?php 

             mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass") or die(mysql_error());

             mysql_select_db("csl") or die(mysql_error());

             $dtb=mysql_query("SHOW TABLES") or die (mysql_error()); 

             $jmltbl=0; $jml_record=0; $jml_record=0; $total =0;


             while($row=mysql_fetch_array($dtb)) 

    { 

 $sql=mysql_query("select * from $row[0]");

 $jml_record=mysql_num_rows($sql);

 $total += $jml_record;   // this counts all the rows





 $jmltbl++; $jml_record+=$jml_record;




    } 
      // echo"--------$jmltbl Tables, $jml_record records."; // will print count of indivual table

echo $total;  // this will print you count of all rows in MySQL database 

       ?>
```

i have tested this code and its works

output 1145 for me

Comment: it  was not slow for me it counted 1145 instantly all other schema related scanrios were not working for me they just gave null results

Comment: -1 for returning all rows of all tables in the entire database. Use `count(*)` instead of `*`.