# MS-SQL - Count all rows per table in a DB per Select Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, information-schema

I wrote this select command, which gives me tables with the associated number of columns from the database.

```
SELECT
    t.TABLE_NAME,
    (SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
      table_name = t.TABLE_NAME) as COLUMNS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
```

I have now tried to extend this and to get the rows as well but i fail all the time. There is a solution in a [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692340/mysql-how-to-count-all-rows-per-table-in-one-query), but I am missing the TABLE_ROWS from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.
Is there maybe another way to get the rows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL count rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916917/sql-count-rows-in-a-table) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917736/2029983) specifically.)

Comment: Yeah, nice. Thanks alot Larnu! Thats what i need. :)

Answer (score 1):

This works perfect. Thanks @Larnu.

```
   SELECT
        t.TABLE_NAME,
        (SELECT
          COUNT(*)
        FROM
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE
          table_name = t.TABLE_NAME) as COLUMNS,
        (select 
            sum([rows])
         from 
            sys.partitions
         where object_id=object_id(t.TABLE_NAME) and index_id in (0,1)) as ROWS
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
```

Comment: Use `sys.tables` rathre than `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Comment: Oh thx. Now I no longer have to exclude the views extra. :)