# Dynamic query string

Tags: mysql

I want to add some dynamic content in from clause based on one particular column value.
is it possible?
For Example,

```
 SELECT BILL.BILL_NO AS BILLNO,
        IF(BILL.PATIENT_ID IS NULL,"CUS.CUSTOMERNAME AS NAME","PAT.PATIENTNAME AS NAME")
 FROM
        BILL_PATIENT_BILL AS BILL 
        LEFT JOIN IF(BILL.PATIENT_ID IS NULL," RT_TICKET_CUSTOMER AS CUS ON BILL.CUSTOMER_ID=CUS.ID"," RT_TICKET_PATIENT AS PAT ON BILL.PATIENT_ID=PAT.ID")
```

But This query is not working.

Here

`BILL_PATIENT_BILL` table is a common table.
It can have either `PATIENT_ID`  or `CUSTOMER_ID`. If a particular record has `PATIENT_ID` i want `PATIENTNAME` in `RT_TICKET_PATIENT`  as NAME OtherWise it will hold `CUSTOMER_ID`. If it is i want `CUSTOMERNAME` as NAME.

Here I m sure That `BILL_PATIENT_BILL` must have either `PATIENT_ID` or `CUSTOMER_ID`.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `IF()` to select the right values instead of constructing your query from strings:

```
 SELECT 
        BILL.BILL_NO AS BILLNO,
        IF( BILL.PATIENT_ID IS NULL, cus.CUSTOMERNAME, pat.PATIENTNAME ) AS NAME
 FROM
        BILL_PATIENT_BILL AS BILL 
 LEFT JOIN RT_TICKET_CUSTOMER cus ON BILL.CUSTOMER_ID = cus.ID
 LEFT JOIN RT_TICKET_PATIENT pat ON BILL.PATIENT_ID = pat.ID
```

However, it would also be possible to `PREPARE` a statement from strings and `EXECUTE` it but this technique is prone to SQL injections, i can only disadvise to do so:

read here: [Is it possible to execute a string in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999200/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-string-in-mysql)