# Use Variable For IN Operation

Tags: mysql

How to use the following variable content for an IN query...

```
SET @var = '1,2,3';
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID IN (@var);
```

Comment: Show the schema of your tables

Comment: you have no `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` in original query `SELECT OtherID FROM Table WHERE X = 1` so it is not 100% equivalent.

Comment: I have editted (instead of deleting) my question to re focus it on the core element of the question... the existing answer was trying to focus on the wrong part.. which is why it is not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found by looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999200/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-string-in-mysql)

```
SET @var = '1,2,3';
SET @Expression=CONCAT('SELECT * FROM TableWHERE ID IN (',@var,')');
PREPARE myquery FROM @Expression;
EXECUTE myquery
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a JOIN

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table t1
JOIN Table t2 on t1.OtherID = t2.OtherID
WHERE t2.X = 1
```

Comment: You can self join the same table. I updated my query

Comment: @Barry what do you mean by _much, much faster_ ? can you provide some numbers? to me the only reason why that trick could be faster is you just did not properly tested mysql caching. so try to run both query with `SQL_NO_CACHE`  to see original performance of each.

Comment: @Barry: And using my query is still slow? Then add an index to column `X`. That should solve your problem