# Is there a way in MySQL to execute a result set from information_schema

Tags: mysql, if-statement, alter

This gives me a list of queries I would like to execute:

```
select CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_name,' DROP edit_time;') AS query FROM information_schema.COLUMNS    where column_name = 'edit_time' AND table_schema = 'homestead';
```

Result:

```
|query|
ALTER TABLE node_fields DROP edit_time;
ALTER TABLE node_list_role DROP edit_time;
ALTER TABLE node_list_versions DROP edit_time;
ALTER TABLE node_lists DROP edit_time;
.. (etc) ..
```

This returns rows of all tables that I want to drop that field on.  But is there any way to do something like:

```
EXECUTE {that query}
```

or

```
FOREACH {results of that query} EXECUTE( {that row} )
```

I don't know mysql procedures or logical statements that well so this is new to me.

Comment: See this question, it's basically what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999200/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-string-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Select all that text into a variable and use it to create a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), which you can then execute.  Be aware that there are some things that are not allowed in a prepared statement, which may include your table modifications.

Edit: As mentioned by @BerndBuffen in the comments below, you can only execute a single query at a time in a prepared statement.  You'll need to loop through the result set of your original query and execute them one at a time -- the following stored procedure should do the trick:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`somebody`@`%` PROCEDURE `test_proc`()
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tname TEXT DEFAULT "";

DECLARE exec_cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS    
    WHERE column_name = 'edit_time' 
    AND table_schema = 'homestead'
    ;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

OPEN exec_cur;

exec_loop: LOOP
    FETCH exec_cur INTO tname;
    IF done THEN 
        LEAVE exec_loop; 
    END IF;

    SET @cmd = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", tname, " DROP edit_time;");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @cmd;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END LOOP exec_loop;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

...or just copy the output rows of your original query, paste them back into your client, and then run them all ;-)

Comment: @A C - You can only execute 1 query as prepared statement

Comment: @BerndBuffen yes, but you can loop over result rows in a stored procedure, creating and executing prepared statements as you go -- good point though, I'll edit as it may not have been obvious to OP