# Simplify recursive mysql query

Tags: mysql, recursion, traversal

With given MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE taxons (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id int,
    name varchar(255)
);
```

The table has following entries

```
INSERT INTO taxons (parent_id, name) VALUES (NULL, "Baby & Kleinkind"); 
INSERT INTO taxons (parent_id, name) VALUES (1, "Babysicherheit"); 
INSERT INTO taxons (parent_id, name) VALUES (2, "Babysicherungen & Schutzvorrichtungen");
```

The amount of levels are endless.

**I want to select a entity (one taxon) with only one query by traversing the tree down.**

Currently my query is kind of handmade

```
SELECT * 
FROM taxons
WHERE name = "Babysicherungen & Schutzvorrichtungen" 
AND parent_id = (
  SELECT id 
  FROM taxons 
  WHERE name  = "Babysicherheit"
  AND parent_id = (
    SELECT id 
    FROM taxons 
    WHERE name = "Baby & Kleinkind"
  )
);
```

Are there any better solutions for this query?

See the db fiddle for better understanding: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mvMCGdNgjCa9PeNKbbzmRL/0

MySQL v5.7

Comment: How many levels do you have? Which is the output you expect? Which version of mysql are you running?

Comment: I created following db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mvMCGdNgjCa9PeNKbbzmRL/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your query correctly, you want to query the top level records, but only those records where all the child rows exist as well. For example, if "Baby & Kleinkind" doesn't exist for some ID, then we don't want that ID.

If so, you could use dynamic SQL to build a query that automatically checks every parent-child relationship for you. If you have a lot of taxons, this could be save you time.

The idea is to build a query that looks like this (assuming that there are five taxons):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM taxons t1
INNER JOIN taxons t2
  ON t1.id = t2.parent_id 
INNER JOIN taxons t3
  ON t2.id = t3.parent_id
INNER JOIN taxons t4
  ON t3.id = t4.parent_id
INNER JOIN taxons t5
  ON t4.id = t5.parent_id
WHERE NAME = "Babysicherungen & Schutzvorrichtungen"
```

To build that, you can use a loop:

```
DECLARE totalLevels INT;
DECLARE num INT;
DECLARE queryString VARCHAR(255);

SET @totalLevels = 5
SET @num = 2;
SET @str = 'SELECT t1.* 
FROM taxons t1';

build_query: LOOP
  IF @num > @totalLevels THEN
    LEAVE build_query;
  END IF;
  SET @queryString = CONCAT(@queryString,
    ' INNER JOIN taxons t', num, ' ON t', num-1, '.id = t', num, '.parent_id'
  );
  SET @num = @num + 1;
  ITERATE build_query;
END LOOP;

SET @queryString = CONCAT(@queryString, ' WHERE NAME = "Babysicherungen & Schutzvorrichtungen"')
```

You use totalLevels to set the total number of taxons that you want to traverse.

I haven't specifically tested the code in that loop, but I've done similar queries in the past, and it should work, or only require minor changes to work.

EDIT: I forgot to add, once you create the query string, you need to execute it. For that, see here:
[Is it possible to execute a string in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999200/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-string-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

A more concise way of expressing this would be to use joins:

```
select t1.* from taxons t1
join taxons t2 on t1.name = "Babysicherungen & Schutzvorrichtungen" and t1.parent_id = t2.id and t2.name = "Babysicherheit"
join taxons t3 on t2.parent_id = t3.id and t3.name="Baby & Kleinkind"
;
```

Given the keys you have defined (or lack thereof), it would also be more efficient. See the two EXPLAIN analysis of your SQL and vs. the above:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE taxons (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id int,
    name varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO taxons (parent_id, name) VALUES (NULL, "Baby & Kleinkind"); 
INSERT INTO taxons (parent_id, name) VALUES (1, "Babysicherheit"); 
INSERT INTO taxons (parent_id, name) VALUES (2, "Babysicherungen & Schutzvorrichtungen");
```

---

**Query #1**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM taxons
WHERE name = "Babysicherungen & Schutzvorrichtungen" 
AND parent_id = (
  SELECT id 
  FROM taxons 
  WHERE name  = "Babysicherheit"
  AND parent_id = (
    SELECT id 
    FROM taxons 
    WHERE name = "Baby & Kleinkind"
  )
);
```

| id  | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra       |
| --- | ----------- | ------ | ---------- | ---- | ------------- | --- | ------- | --- |

```
---- | -------- | ----------- |
| 1   | PRIMARY     | taxons |            | ALL  |               |     |         |     | 3    | 33.33    | Using where |
| 2   | SUBQUERY    | taxons |            | ALL  |               |     |         |     | 3    | 33.33    | Using where |
| 3   | SUBQUERY    | taxons |            | ALL  |               |     |         |     | 3    | 33.33    | Using where |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3DbWgWkXMUeFxFMTAvCggV/2)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE taxons (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id int,
    name varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO taxons (parent_id, name) VALUES (NULL, "Baby & Kleinkind"); 
INSERT INTO taxons (parent_id, name) VALUES (1, "Babysicherheit"); 
INSERT INTO taxons (parent_id, name) VALUES (2, "Babysicherungen & Schutzvorrichtungen");
```

---

**Query #1**

```
EXPLAIN select t1.* from taxons t1
join taxons t2 on t1.name = "Babysicherungen & Schutzvorrichtungen" and t1.parent_id = t2.id and t2.name = "Babysicherheit"
join taxons t3 on t2.parent_id = t3.id and t3.name="Baby & Kleinkind"
;

| id  | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref               | rows | filtered | Extra       |
| --- | ----------- | ----- | ---------- | ------ | ------------- | ------- | ------- | ----------------- | ---- | -------- | ----------- |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | t1    |            | ALL    |               |         |         |                   | 3    | 33.33    | Using where |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | t2    |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.t1.parent_id | 1    | 33.33    | Using where |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | t3    |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.t2.parent_id | 1    | 33.33    | Using where |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Te67617bb11g6Eq2yB6vs/1)

Comment: Great! Didn't thought about joins!