# SQL - How to use SUBSTRING function to output as Col Name

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use the SUBSTRING function in SQL to output the result as Column Name?

Example:

```
DECLARE @itemname VARCHAR(50) = 'HELLO WORLD'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@itemname, 1, 5) AS OUTPUT
```

Gives the output as

```
OUTPUT
-----
HELLO
```

What I want to achieve here is that the Col name should instead be given out as HELLO

```
DECLARE @itemname VARCHAR(50) = 'HELLO WORLD'

SELECT col1 AS SUBSTRING(@itemname, 1, 5)
FROM myTable
```

Which should display

```
HELLO
------
Record 1
Record 2
Record 3
Record 4
.
.
.
```

Comment: No, you cannot readily do that in a SELECT statement.  You need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic sql for that purüose, as you can't do it drectly

> ```
> CREATE TABLE myTable(i int)
> ```

> ```
> SET @itemname  := 'HELLO WORLD';
>
>     SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) AS ', SUBSTRING(@itemname, 1, 5), ' FROM myTable');
>
>
>     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
>     EXECUTE stmt;
>     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> | HELLO |
> | ----: |
> |     0 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae60f896006a67bb48c032c3bf9a152c)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL :

```
DECLARE @itemname VARCHAR(50) = 'HELLO WORLD'
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT col1 AS ', SUBSTRING(@itemname, 1, 5), ' FROM myTable');
```

This outputs

```
SELECT col1 AS HELLO FROM myTable
```

Now, you can copy paste that result or [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html) it

Here are more informations about the usage of `EXECUTE` : [Is it possible to execute a string in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999200/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-string-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I think you misunderstood what I was trying to achieve here. Let me rephrase, I would like to Alias a column name using a SUBSTRING function for a declared item.

Comment: I perfectly understood your question, but it would need an extra step to be achieved