# I have 203 tables in my database and I want to write a query which returns all of the latest rows for each table

Tags: sql

I have 203 tables in my SQL database, I want to print the latest records for each table. I know the query to get the latest row of one table at one time. How do I query for the latest row of each table in one go?

Comment: What is your database engine?

Comment: How do you determine what the "latest row" is in each table? Remember that database engines _don't actually_ keep track of the last-written-row in each table (surprisingly, there's a _lot_ of things that RDBMS _don't do_, even today...) so the only way to do that _correctly_ is by having a `rowversion` column or be using a temporal-table (with `PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME` columns), or have a meticulously designed DB with triggers to ensure last-modified timestamps are always correct. Now, you could check for the `MAX` value in an `IDENTITY` (aka `AUTO_INCREMENT`) but that doesn't track `UPDATE`.

Comment: what is you query for latest record of one table at one time ? you want to get 1 latest result from all table at a time ?

Comment: You need one column is same for all table because of order class need to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I do not know what are the names of your DB. So I assume that they can be indexed in the way I am about to show:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter=1
WHILE ( @Counter <= 203)
BEGIN
    EXEC('SELECT TOP(5) * FROM TABLE_'+@Counter+'ORDER BY Date DESC')
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```

Here make sure that you have defined everything using dynamic queries. In addition, I did not know in what format you need your pulled results to look.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SHOW TABLES` and [`GROUP CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) and

```
SET @Expression = SELECT CONCAT('SELECT...
                  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(...
PREPARE myquery FROM @Expression;
EXECUTE myquery;
```

[Is it possible to execute a string in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999200/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-string-in-mysql)

Comment: It will take some creativity to join all the tables into one query using `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT`